# Difference between style of defining setter and getter in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, getter-setter

I was exploring setter and getter in JavaScript:

## CODE1:

http://jsfiddle.net/imrukhan/7j8ZS/3/

ref : http://whereswalden.com/2010/04/16/more-spidermonkey-changes-ancient-esoteric-very-rarely-used-syntax-for-creating-getters-and-setters-is-being-removed/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var Person = function(name){
                this.name = name;
                defineGetter(this, "Name", function() {
                    console.log("inside getter method");
                    return this.name;
                }); 
                defineSetter(this, "Name", function(val) {
                    console.log("inside setter method");
                    this.name = val;
                }); 
            }
            function accessorDescriptor(field, fun) {
              var desc = { enumerable: true, configurable: true };
              desc[field] = fun;
              return desc;
            }

            function defineGetter(obj, prop, get) {

                if (Object.defineProperty)
                    return Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, accessorDescriptor("get", get));
                if (Object.prototype.__defineGetter__)
                    return obj.__defineGetter__(prop, get);

                throw new Error("browser does not support getters");
            }

            function defineSetter(obj, prop, set) {

                if (Object.defineProperty)
                    return Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, accessorDescriptor("set", set));
                if (Object.prototype.__defineSetter__)
                    return obj.__defineSetter__(prop, set);

                throw new Error("browser does not support setters");
            }

            function fun(){
                var per = new Person("ABC");
                console.log(per.Name);
                per.Name = "XYZ";
                console.log(per.Name);
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="click" onclick="fun()"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

## CODE2:

http://jsfiddle.net/imrukhan/9H2U6/1/

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Using_object_initializers

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            var Person = function(name) {
                this._name = name;
            };

            Object.defineProperty(Person.prototype, "name", {
                get: function() {
                    console.log("inside getter method");
                    return this._name;
                },
                set: function(val){
                    console.log("inside setter method");
                    this._name = val;
                }
            });

            function fun(){
                var per = new Person("ABC");
                console.log(per.name);
                per.name = "XYZ";
                console.log(per.name);
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="button" value="click" onclick="fun()"/>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

My Queries:
1) Is there any functional difference between CODE1 & CODE2 except style ?
2) What is the best way to define a Setter and Getter in JavaScipt (CODE1 /CODE2 /Please suggest any other)?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: 1. Personally, I find CODE2 above easier to read and maintain; 2. Depends what you mean by 'best way': maintenance/speed/readability? Regarding speed, have a look at this [comparison](http://jsperf.com/getter-setter/77).

Comment: Nicolae, we can discuss all the possible ways in terms of maintenance/speed/readability.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should consider in the code is:

In CODE1 each instance of the Person will have own methods for getter and setter. It means if you create 10 persons, you will have 20 methods for getters and setters.

While in CODE2 it will create only one getter and one setter methods that will be shared by all instances of Person.

So if you're going for Web/App that can create lots of instances, you should definitely go with the CODE2.

Comment: Very important difference! Prototyping ftw.

Answer (score 0):

CODE1 uses the ECMA5 standard if available otherwise falls back to the non-standard.

CODE2 uses the ECMA5 standard only.

Best depends on the environment you are coding for, wider browser support or just ECMA5.

I believe the following three links should give you all the information that you require.

[defineGetter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineGetter)

[defineProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty)

[Defining getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters)

Sure there are many ways of writing your example codes in other manners, 2 examples.

Variation of CODE1, (feature detect once, assign to `prototype`)

```
var defineGetter,
    defineSetter;

function accessorDescriptor(field, fun) {
    var desc = {
        enumerable: true,
        configurable: true
    };

    desc[field] = fun;
    return desc;
}

if (Object.defineProperty) {
    defineGetter = function defineGetter(obj, prop, get) {
        return Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, accessorDescriptor("get", get));
    };

    defineSetter = function (obj, prop, set) {
        return Object.defineProperty(obj, prop, accessorDescriptor("set", set));
    };
} else {
    if (Object.prototype.__defineGetter__) {
        defineGetter = function (obj, prop, get) {
            return obj.__defineGetter__(prop, get);
        };
    } else {
        throw new Error("browser does not support getters");
    }

    if (Object.prototype.__defineSetter__) {
        defineSetter = function (obj, prop, set) {
            return obj.__defineSetter__(prop, set);
        };
    } else {
        throw new Error("browser does not support setters");
    }
}

function Person(name) {
    this.name = name;
};

defineGetter(Person.prototype, "Name", function () {
    console.log("inside getter method");
    return this.name;
});

defineSetter(Person.prototype, "Name", function (val) {
    console.log("inside setter method");
    this.name = val;
});
```

Variation of CODE2 (without `defineProperty`)

```
var Person = function (name) {
    this.name = name;
};

Person.prototype.name = {
    get: function () {
        console.log("inside getter method");
        return this.name;
    },

    set: function (val) {
        console.log("inside setter method");
        this.name = val;
    }
};
```

Comment: Xotic750, Thank you for your suggestion and variation of code. Lets see the others opinion.